# Chrome - утечка памяти при POS-инге base64 изображения в input-е - что делать?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory, утечка-памяти

Мне необходимо отправить через форму base64 изображение на сервер. Base64 изображение находится в input-е(hidden).

Размер картинки ~1.1мб, 2500x1700, base64 размер ~1.5мб.
Проблема проявляется и при меньших размерах.

Я загружаю изображение через input file, затем через FileReader преобразую в base64 и помещаю значение в input hidden. input[type=file].value я затем очищаю.

При попытке отправить содержимое формы, вкладка виснет, а расход памяти подскакивает с 50% до 93% (4Гигабайта оперативной памяти), после чего хром крашится.

Когда я попытался отправить форму в Firefox, все прошло быстро и без дополнительных выделений памяти.

Я понимаю, что это баг Хрома (и напишу им, конечно же), но может кто-то уже сталкивался с этим и знает временное решение?

---

Ок, если я присваиваю значение **e.target.result** к input.value в FileReader onload, то в результате получается утечка памяти. Однако, если присвоить input.value равный по длине любой текст, то утечки памяти нет.
Не думаю, что e.target.result может косвенно удерживать FileReader от сборки (хотя... может?), т.к. это строка. Так что получение результата от FileReader-а забаговано. Что делать?

Comment: А почему, собственно, нельзя отправлять на сервер сам файл?

Comment: Потому что у меня input file multiple, т.е. юзер может выбрать несколько файлов. Но он должен иметь возможность отменить отправку любого из выбранных файлов. А управлять input.files нельзя, т.к. readonly

Comment: Посмотрите как реализовано в [`jquery file upload`](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/). Вкратце - после выбора пользователем файлов они изымаются из инпута и загружаются в фоне аяксом.

Comment: А потом, при необходимости удаления файла, приходится либо делать дополнительные AJAX-запросы, либо составлять список файлов для удаления/оставления в живых в форме. Это все тоже не очень-то хорошо.

Comment: А в чем проблема сделать дополнительный ajax-запрос? Невысокая цена за нормальную индикацию процесса загрузки файла.